# Автоматическая вставка текущей даты и времени при добавление записи в таблицу

Tags: sql-server, mvc

**Цель:** Нужно реализовать автоматическую вставку текущей даты и времени при добавлении записи в таблицу (IDStudent).

```
    public class Students
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int StudentsId { get; set; }      
    public string IDStudent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; } /* **???** */
}
```

Данные в db уже есть и нужно только добавить или создать новый IDStudent.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {        
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IDStudent, new { @class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessage("IDStudent")
            <div class="">
                <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
    }
```

При сохранении IDStudent автоматически сохранялась дата и время.

От куда брать дату и время? В контроллере и предавать ее строкой в базу данных или через sql? Как это реализовать и как проще?

Только познаю программирование и mvc. Заранее Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Какой подход используется ? Используете EF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать несколькими способами:

1. Написать триггер:

   ```
   create trigger insertToStudentsTrigger
   on Students for insert as 
   if @@rowcount=1
   begin
       update Students
       set datetime=getdate()
       where id=inserted.id
   end
   ```
2. Задать в базе некоторое значение, которое будет вставляться по
   умолчанию

   ```
   [ExampleDateTime] DATETIME DEFAULT getdate() NOT NULL
   ```

   [Список функций и типов для работы с датой и временем (T-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)
3. Задавать явно в вашем методе который вставляет значение в БД

   ```
   student.datetime = DateTime.Now;
   ```